# 403 PHP Error- Caused by HTML?

Tags: php, html, include, html-lists, http-status-code-403

My web page works fine most of the time. It is called `myschedule.php` It includes a bunch of other PHP files, and all of them work except for one, `content_dashboard.php`, I've narrowed down the error to somewhere within this code:

```
echo '
        <!--Student Dashboard-->
        <div class="featuredcontent">
            <div id="titlebar">Dashboard</div>
            <div id="titlebarminimize" onclick="studentdashboardtoggle();">_</div>
            <div id="titlebarclose" onclick="studentdashboardclose();">X</div>
        </div>

        <div id="studentstudentdashboard">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://mail.google.com/"><img src="studentdashboard/gmail.png"> Prep Mail</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://sites.google.com/a/thecollegepreparatoryschool.org/student-dashboard/home"><img src="studentdashboard/studentdashboard.png"> Student Dashboard</a></li>
            </ul></div>
            <hr style="color:#85B3FF;">
            <div id="homeworklog"></div>

        </div>';
```

Everything looks fine, the JS functions are correct, the links work, the images are correctly sourced, and the syntax looks good.

I commented out everything after the first `<ul>` and everything worked fine, but if I let the PHP file echo anything after that, the webpage redirects me to a 403 Error page.

Any pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Also- my hosting provider is AwardSpace.com, and I have a FREE Hosting Account, though I don't think that should matter...

Comment: I'm not sure if the syntax highlighter is off, but it looks like you're ending the string here --> `</ul></div>';` that single quote looks out of place, or you just forgot to add another `echo` after it to restart the echo.

Comment: oops yeah- that was a leftover bit of code from my commenting rampage to try to find the error- I just fixed it in the original post but it doesn't seem to fix anything on my website

Comment: Well, as far as I know HTML does not generate error messages; it just doesn't show up. Most likely it's the PHP, however the error code 403 means forbidden

Comment: Exactly- that's why I'm really confused with this case- it just doesn't make any sense

Comment: Wait- just found something- The error is specifically caused by including the first `<a href>` tag

Comment: I think I know the issue then. Try removing the slash at the end of the href url

Comment: No value in a `href` should make your site return a 403. I'd check with your webhost to see if they have some weird setting or filter.

Comment: Yeah- I just googled awardspace link blocked and found a blog where they had previously blocked sites like aol.com and amazon.com to prevent phishing...I'll do a little more investigating on this

Answer (score 0):

As was my initial suspicion, Awardspace blocked certain keywords it deemed "malicious" as sort of a failsafe way to prevent all websites that might be phishing. Here is my correspondence email in case anyone had the same problem with Awardspace:

AWARDSPACE- WedAug 7 2013 5:38am - Collin Brice
Hello,

Thank you for contacting us.

We've made some more tests using a proxy server and the page in mentioned of your website is indeed being blocked by our filtering system.
Unfortunately the system is in place on our free servers because of the huge amount of abusive websites coming out of them and it cannot be stopped. We are sorry if this causes you any inconvenience, but this is our free hosting policy.

Feel free to reopen this ticket in case you have more questions or you need further assistance.

Thank you for choosing our services.

Best Regards,
Collin Brice
Dedicated Support Team
Supportindeed.com